# Android- Adding item to ListView from another activity onButtonClick

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm not sure why my code isn't working, I've looked at the rest of the threads on this site and followed the directions but there still seems to be some error.

In my app, there is a page for a user to enter some data, including dates, descriptions, hours, and minutes of duration. The description/date are Strings and hours and minutes are ints. I've focused on only the String date for now to simplify things.

After the user enters this data in the activity, they will click the "Submit" button. When they click this submit button, I want the user to be taken to another page where they will be able to see a history of their submitions in a ListView.

In the first Activity, when the "Submit" button is clicked, this method will be called:

```
public void newEntrySubmit(View v)
{
    hours = npHours.getValue();
    minutes = npMinutes.getValue();
    description=String.valueOf(etDescription.getText().toString());
    dateOfPractice=String.valueOf(etDate.getText().toString());

    Intent i = new Intent(this, PreviousPractices.class);
    i.putExtra("Hours", hours);
    i.putExtra("Minutes", minutes);
    i.putExtra("Description", description);
    i.putExtra("dateOfPractice", dateOfPractice);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

After this, the PreviousPractices class should open. The onCreate method for this class is shown:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.previous_practices_layout);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    hours = extras.getInt("Hours");
    minutes = extras.getInt("Minutes");
    description=extras.getString("Description");
    date = extras.getString("Date");

    practiceList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.practiceList);
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
    practiceList.setAdapter(adapter);
    listItems.add(date);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The problem is that when I click the "Submit" button, the app crashes. When I remove the

```
practiceList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

line, it successfully goes to the correct ListView page, however there is nothing shown(since no adapter is set).

Comment: post your error log here.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Also, you don't have an extra for "Date" so there will be nothing added to your ArrayList. Try testing with "Description" instead.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference, and then a bunch of android.view and .widget problems, nested into that. I'm entering something for every field

Comment: Solved it. The only problem was that I mistakenly had the key as "Date" instead of "dateOfPractice".

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said earlier. No "Date".

Comment: Do you know how I can keep the listView from resetting every time I add a new log? It only shows one item at a time.

Comment: You need to store your collection of data somewhere. Either save to SharedPrefs or use a SQLite database. There's lots of info about those in the official Android Developer guide and training docs. Basically, first activity should add new log data to your storage location. Second activity should then load all data into your ArrayList and then display in ListView. If loading from db, you'll probably want to use a cursor and cursor adapter instead of ArrayAdapter. Try it. If you still need more help, start another question with your updated code. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.previous_practices_layout);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    hours = extras.getInt("Hours");
    minutes = extras.getInt("Minutes");
    description=extras.getString("Description");
    // date = extras.getString("Date");

    practiceList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.practiceList);
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    listItems.add(description);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
    practiceList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I changed your test string to description, since date is not getting set (no extra for "Date" in previous activity). Also, I moved your ArrayList.add() to before your ListView.setAdapter(). Try this and see if it works.